# selenium or loadtest for nodejs apis load testing

Tags: node.js, selenium, load

I am trying to do load test on server to know the approx maximum connection possible on VM.

Some one suggested selenium is one better options for load testing. I just wanted to do the load test not the functionality test.

This is nodejs load test library
https://www.npmjs.com/package/loadtest

which is better **Selenium** or **loadtest**?

I am a newb in this.

Comment: Use Apache Jmeter for load testing

Answer (score 0):

This is not "fair" comparison.

The loadtest this is a library allows to run requests and then you have to process the responses by yourself. This tool allows to you to simulate the system behaviour on the underneath (request) level.

Selenium is taking another approach. With selenium you may to simulate the real user scenario w/o taking in consideration the specific requests. 
Usually selenium requires much more machine resources than other tools. In order to provide the load test with selenium you should be able to load the number of virtual machines that proportional to the the system real users.

The loadtest not required such big number of machines because you usually able to simulate many users from the single (or few) machine.
The tool that today is most common in the industry is Jmeter as @Jitendra Kumar is mentioned. This tool has friendly user interface and allows generate many requests from the single machine.

You also may to take a look on [Gatling](http://gatling.io/) tool which also simulate requests in Scala language.

Answer (score 0):

In my case , I had a nodejs based server. I first created a test case using Firefox and jmeter.

you should use old firefox version i.e. 47 and below. You run your application(browser , Cordova , ionic) on browser and record it using jmeter and run the same for as many as client you want in same jmeter.

below is the link

https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf